# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int' with a csv file

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am trying to find specific elements (those with a value less than 5) in a particular data column from an imported csv file. However I keep encountering this strange error. The code reads as follows:

````
z = np.loadtxt('exoplanets_nasa_archive.csv', delimiter= ',', dtype=str )

zlabels = z[0]

#print(zlabels)

mass =z[1:, 9]

subfive =np.where(mass<5)```

#The output error reads:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-af2622a146c5> in <module>()
----> 1 subfive =np.where(mass<5)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
````

Comment: The error message seems quite clear: you're trying to use `where` to compare items of different shapes, and that is not supported -- just as the documentation tells you.

Comment: Doesn't numpy.where usually work by comparing array elements and integers? I tried it on other similar csv files and got so such error.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data? I suspect your dtype may be causing problems.

Comment: Printing the data itself shows it to be a simple array of floats, but printing mass.dtype gives the data type of "<U29"

Comment: @Declan you've specified dtype=str. '<U29' is a string of length 29... You probably want a numerical type for mass. Also what versions are you using of Python and numpy?

Comment: I know, it makes no sense. I'm using jupyter notebook, which I believe uses python 3

Comment: @rkedge that's it! I just had to chanfe the data type to float! I initially imported it all as str because it wouldn't import otherwise, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are doing:

```
In [78]: mass = np.array([1.23, 123.3], dtype='U32')
In [79]: mass
Out[79]: array(['1.23', '123.3'], dtype='<U32')
In [80]: mass<5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-80-39e4c1351b25>", line 1, in <module>
    mass<5
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

I'm a little surprised that it isn't complaining about instances of string (or string dtype) and int.

With `loadtxt` the default dtype is float, and it raises an error if some strings can't be parsed as floats.  `np.genfromtxt` assigns those values `nan` instead.